# Kafka can't delete topic and reopen fail when delete topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Every topic I create in Kafka and delete it.

`.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat  --zookeeper localhost:2181  --delete --topic linlin6`

they always say 
`Topic linlin6 is marked for deletion.`

I set the `delete.topic.enable=true` in `server.properties`
and it shows the same message to me and next time I start zookeeper 
and Kafka will give me error like this:

```
        java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\WEBSOCKET\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\logs\linlin6-0 -> D:\WEBSOCKET\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\logs\linlin6-0.bd274201d28e45caa9b23ed1cd0ac56e-delete
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:809)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$renameDir$2(Log.scala:728)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at kafka.log.Log.maybeHandleIOException(Log.scala:1927)
    at kafka.log.Log.renameDir(Log.scala:726)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.asyncDelete(LogManager.scala:842)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$delete$1(Partition.scala:353)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:259)
    at kafka.cluster.Partition.delete(Partition.scala:347)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopReplica(ReplicaManager.scala:350)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$stopReplicas$2(ReplicaManager.scala:380)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopReplicas(ReplicaManager.scala:378)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleStopReplicaRequest(KafkaApis.scala:200)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:111)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Suppressed: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\WEBSOCKET\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\logs\linlin6-0 -> D:\WEBSOCKET\kafka_2.12-2.1.0\logs\linlin6-0.bd274201d28e45caa9b23ed1cd0ac56e-delete
```

Event I set the delete.topic.enable=true it will say :
Topic linlin6 is marked for deletion.

and can't open it again next time through me delete the logs in Kafka
and data in zookeeper...

Where am I setting wrong or doing wrong?

Comment: check whether your Kafka broker is running. When you delete a topic in kafka, it is marked for deletion in zookeeper, when the partitions for that topic is not running

Comment: I am not clear, could you please explain a bit , what exactly needs to be done ?